# TCL: Can I extract a procedure from a script file without sourcing it?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit, tclsh

I was wondering if there is a way to extract a procedure from another script without sourcing all of it.
The goal in this case is to not create a new file with the methods separated from the main script file, but to use the procs that are into that script.

I have use open, read and source and eval.

Comment: How about create a slave interpreter, then source another script file in the slave? After that, use "info body" to get procedure contents from the proc in slave. Thus it won't mess up your main script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation of `source` is *almost exactly* like `open`+`read`+`eval` (except with the C API). It isn't smart.

In general, getting the contents of a procedure can only be done by using `info body` after it has been created (plus `info args` and `info default`). But *often* people write code such that the word `proc` is in the first column of a line and the body is all indented, with first following non-indented line being the closing `}`. That won't work in all cases (the main trickiness is when `namespace eval` is in use) but will in many. Even then, the word `proc` is probably the first on its line (with indenting) and the close-brace is aligned with it.

I'm one of the few people that really writes code that doesn't always follow this convention. You don't need to worry about me.

Comment: Thank you Donal, I found one question than another person made about how to replicate the if __main__ of python and you answered with a great solution that solves this too. I am evaluating that option. Thank you!